# elasticsearch service fails to start after installation

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed elastic search using the deb package from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch). The service however fails to start and throws below error. How can I fix this?

```
    $ sudo service elasticsearch restart
  * Stopping Elasticsearch Server      [ OK ]
  * Starting Elasticsearch Server
  chown: invalid group: `elasticsearch:elasticsearch'
  chown: invalid group: `elasticsearch:elasticsearch'    [fail]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have this user/group set up in your system:

For security reasons, running the server as an unprivileged user and group is strongly encouraged. Create user and group for Elasticsearch:

`groupadd elasticsearch`

`useradd -s /sbin/nologin -d /usr/local/elasticsearch -c "Elasticsearch User"`

Comment: `sudo groupadd elasticsearch` fixed the problem.